Why does Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests increase by 400 for a simple indexed query?
I am monitoring the Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests before and after executing my query on a MySQL, and I noticed that it increases by approximately 400, even though my query is very simple.
Here is my query:
SELECT *  
FROM my_table t  
WHERE t.a = 20000  
LIMIT 1;  

The column a has an index, and the query is confirmed to use the index correctly.
Below is the status difference before and after executing the query:
┌──────────────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ (index)                          │ Values │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────┤
│ Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests │ 400    │
│ Innodb_buffer_pool_reads         │ 0      │
│ Handler_read_first               │ 0      │
│ Handler_read_key                 │ 1      │
│ Handler_read_last                │ 0      │
│ Handler_read_next                │ 0      │
│ Handler_read_prev                │ 0      │
│ Handler_read_rnd                 │ 0      │
│ Handler_read_rnd_next            │ 0      │
└──────────────────────────────────┴────────┘

I don’t understand why Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests increases by 400 when Handler_read_key only increases by 1. This behavior is consistent across multiple executions.
Can someone explain why this happens?

November 28 Update
Here is my table schema:
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id         INT UNSIGNED                       NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY,
    a          INT UNSIGNED                       NOT NULL,
    b          INT UNSIGNED                       NOT NULL,
    contents   VARCHAR(255)                       NOT NULL,
    deleted_at DATETIME                           NULL,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ix_a
    ON my_table (a);

CREATE INDEX ix_b
    ON my_table (b);

I am running MySQL version 8.0.40 in a Docker container.
No configurations have been modified from the default.
It is running on my local PC, and I am the only user.

You haven't shown the definition of your table, so one can only guess if you have large BLOB/TEXT/JSON columns that span many pages. Or it may have to read a chain of previous row versions if you have a lot of concurrent updates.

I think it's accessing index pages as well as the data page. But 400 seems high. I tested, and I got a max of 12 page read requests. I don't know how many rows you have in your table, perhaps it's millions. I tested with a few thousand rows.
